# C# use WH_MOUSE

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm making mouse listener in wpf, and I see that I need to use WH_MOUSE, but unfortunately it generates error (I don't have it).
How Do I import it to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the trick is to use [Brushes.Transparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes.transparent) for the `Background`. By default, the `Background` is `null`, which lets you click through to the elements below. When you use `Transparent` instead, the background is still see-through, but it responds to input like mouse clicks.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rect" MouseLeftButtonDown="leftDown" Fill="Transparent" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!